# I do want each multiprocessing pool worker to have its own copy of the global variable and be able to modify it

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want each process to have it's own copy of global variable and process should be able to modify  and store the global variable :

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
input = [1,10]
first = 0
def printer (input) :
    global first
    first += input
    print('input', input)
    print('for input',input ,'first' , first)

def pool_handler():
    p = Pool(2)
    p.map(printer, input)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        pool_handler()
        time.sleep(5)
```

My current output is

```
input 1
for input 1 first 1
input 10
for input 10 first 10 
input 1
for input 1 first 1
input 10
for input 10 first 10
...
```

WHere as my expected output is

```
input 1
for input 1 first 1
input 10
for input 10 first 10
input 1
for input 1 first 2
input 10
for input 10 first 20
```

Comment: I don't understand - you want the global to be shared, or not shared?

Comment: I don't want them to be shared , Each pool should have a global variable , and it should update when function is called .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we print process id, we can see each worker has its own variables :

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import time
input = [1,10]
first = 0
def printer (input) :
    global first
    first += input
    print(f'Process {os.getpid()} for input={input} first={first}')

def pool_handler(p):
    p.map(printer, input)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(2)
    while True:
        pool_handler(p)
        time.sleep(5)
```

I put pool allocation before the while loop.

Comment: I tried  running your code and , some times it gives expected results , but sometimes it  gives different result . and i am using the same code each time .

Comment: Agree. Different results but all confirm each process has its own global variables

Comment: global variable is getting mixed :  somtimes i get results where , for input 1 first 1 , then in next time for input 10 first is 11

Comment: That is logic, the count gets accumulated in the same process.

Comment: No , there is one process for 1 , and 2nd process for 10 , so for 1 count should be 1,2,3,4.... and for input 10 there is different process and count shoud be 10,20,30,40....

Comment: Sometimes python seems to feed both 1 and 10 to the same process. Can you paste results ?

Comment: Where is the process number ?

Comment: Process 40496 for input=1 first=1
Process 40496 for input=10 first=11
Process 40496 for input=1 first=12
Process 20488 for input=10 first=10
Process 40496 for input=1 first=13
Process 20488 for input=10 first=20
Process 40496 for input=1 first=14
Process 20488 for input=10 first=30
Process 40496 for input=1 first=15
Process 20488 for input=10 first=40
Process 40496 for input=1 first=16
Process 20488 for input=10 first=50

Comment: You can see Python feeds both 1 and 10 to process 40496.

Comment: ya , i just noticed that , what can i do to avoid that .

Comment: so i read about pool and is says that process is created and all tasks are queued and task is assigned to whichever process is free . that is why  task of input 10 is  assigned to same process .

Comment: Yes you are right, if you want to go your way, just create two process and you distribute whatever way you like.

Answer (score 0):

So It is not possible with multiprocessing.pool to create different processes where each process has it's own copy of global variable . Since when pools are created all tasks are queued and and tasks are assigned to whichever pool is free .

So for my problem now i am using multiprocessing.process , I created two processes and now each has it's own copy of global variable , and each process can store and modify global variable . Below i am posting my current code .

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool,process,Process
import os
import time
#input = [1,10]
first = 0
def printer (input) :
    while True :
        global first
        first += input
        print(f'Process {os.getpid()} for input={input} first={first}')
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=printer, args=(1,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=printer, args=(10,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
```

and I had to move while True code in my function because once a process is terminated it can not restart the same process.